# Keyboard shortcut to scroll to the top of a webpage?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I was wondering if anyone know of any keyboard shortcuts to scroll to the top of a webpage in Chrome?

The current solution I use is to hold the keys <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and wait for it to scroll to the top but when the document gets longer, this can be troublesome, often requiring a few seconds just to get to the top of the page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried the <kbd>Home</kbd>  ?

A complete list of Chrome shortcuts can be found [on this Google page](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_key

Comment: If you are focused within an editor window or textarea, the `Home` or the `Ctrl` + `Home` shortcut does not jump to the top of the page. It stays focused within the textarea.